# Print from specific row of csv file

Tags: python, csv

my csv file has multiple tables in a single file for example

```
name age gender
n1    10  f
n2    20  m
n3    30  m
city  population 
city1   10
city2   20
city3   30
```

How can I print from city row to city3 row.using python csv module

Answer (score 2):

You need to come up with a way to detect the start and end of the relevant section of the file; the `csv` module does not contain any built-in mechanism for doing this by itself, because there is no general and unambiguous delimiter for the beginning and end of a particular section.

I have to question the wisdom of jamming multiple CSV files together like this. Is there a reason that you can't separate the sections into  individual files?

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper `csv` module for the question. Alternatively, you can probably use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module for regular expression match.

An example:

```
with open("file.csv") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
cities = [re.findall("(city.*)", line)[0] for line in data]
print cities
```

it should print all lines begin with keyword "city".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  What's wrong with [13.1 CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for Python 2.x and [14.1 CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv) for Python 3.x?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ah, I didn't look for `csv` module anytime before. But the format this question posted doesn't look like a `.csv`

Comment: Yes...CSV is an abused term.  Sometimes, as here, it would probably be better termed DSV - Delimiter-Separated Variable format.  It looks like the delimiter is probably a tab, here.  The Python CSV module can handle a number of variants on CSV format, and specifically it could handle this one — or, at least, either of the sections of it, but maybe not the two sections jammed together.

Comment: The `csv` module can actual deal with many similar forms of text tables divided into rows and columns with delimiter characters... Not just those that are truly *comma*-separated.

Comment: @DanLenski As `csv` is really a simple format, I'd just like to read them using regular expression and list comprehension.

Comment: Reading CSV files with regular expressions is quite a bad idea in my opinion. As discussed, Python has a module which can handle related formats in a flexible and customizable way; it handles various delimiters and quoting conventions, and every experienced Python programmer knows what to expect from it. Why would you reinvent the wheel with a solution that is likely to be slower, buggy, and less flexible?

Comment: @DanLenski I have never came up with a condition that I have to _parse_ a csv file using a module, except for those sophisticated as html format, I would choose BeautifulSoup...In my experience, more detailed works will require digging into cvs data, finding patterns, which may also require regular expression match. Moreover, I've never been stuck on bugs reading csv. It takes me less than one minute to retrieve the data.

Comment: What does `BeautifulSoup` have to do with CSV files? Regardless of what kind of data the CSV file contains, you still need to parse it to extract the desired rows/columns before doing anything else with the data... unless you are suggesting that you can just blindly search for patterns while ignoring the tabular structure of the data??

Comment: @DanLenski help me, I've just mentioned `BeautifulSoup` for a comparison with `html` format.